# Stripe - Not charging card

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I've setup a stripe custom checkout using javascript. Every parameter goes through, I receive a status 200 in the log when we make a payment. Everything looks like it goes through. However the amount remains as "0" in the Parsed Request Query Parameters and not charging the card.

I've gone over documentation for hours and can't get my head around the issue.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
  var pinId = "<%= @id %>";
  var from = "<%= @from %>";
  var content = "Supersize+me";
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'Published-Key',
    image: '/assets/campusboard-logo.png',
    token: function(token, args) {
        $.getJSON( "purchased/"+pinId )
          .done(function( data ) {
             window.location = "http://"+window.location.host+"/pins/"+pinId+"?utm_source=Purchased&utm_medium="+from+"&utm_campaign=Featured%20Pins&utm_content="+content;
           })
          .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            alert("We've encountered a problem with the transaction. Please try again.");
        });
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('ssm').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'CampusBoard',
      description: 'Featured Pin (£29.00)',
      amount: "100",
      currency: 'GBP',
      panelLabel: 'Supersize my Pin'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  document.getElementById('mmh').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'CampusBoard',
      description: 'Featured Pin (£59.00)',
      amount: 5900,
      currency: 'GBP',
      panelLabel: 'Make my Pin Huge'
    });
    content = "Make+me+huge";
    e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

Can someone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Stripe Checkout is just a well-done pre-made payment form. You actually have to create a Charge object on your server using your Stripe secret API key. Follow [these tutorials](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges) for your specific language.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the amount as a string whereas I think stripe is expecting it as a number. So:

```
handler.open({
  ...
  amount: 100,
  ...
});
```

Comment: Although I now notice you've got it mixed between the two calls. Do they both fail?